# PHP urlencode for chinese characters

Tags: php, utf-8, urlencode, url-encoding

I'm creating a php application that involves sending chinese characters as url parameters.

I have to send query like :

`http://xyz.com/?q=新`

But the script at xyz.com won't automatically encode the chinese character. So, I need to explicitly send an encoded string as the paramter. It becomes:

`http://xyz.com/?q=%E6%96%B0`

The problem is, PHP won't encode the chinese character properly.

I've tried `urlencode()` and `rawurlencode()`. But they give `%D0%C2` (doesn't work for my purpose) instead of `%E6%96%B0` (works well with xyz.com) as the output.

I'm using [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) website to create the latter encoded string.

I've also defined `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=gb2312');` to display chinese characters properly.

Is there anything I can do to urlencode the chinese character properly?

Thanks!

PS: I'm a relatively new programmer and don't understand chinese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're URLencoding using the charset you specify in your header. *%D0%C2* is 新 in gb2312; *%E6%96%B0* is 新 in UTF-8. Switch your charset over to UTF-8 and you should fix this issue and still be able to display Simplified Chinese Han.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reproduce your problem I created a simple PHP file:

```
<?php
var_dump(urlencode('新'));
?>
```

First I used UTF8 encoding and got `%E6%96%B0`. Afterwards I changed to GB2312 and got `%D0%C2`.

At http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ they seem to use JavaScript, that's UTF8 capable and therefore returns `%E6%96%B0`, too.

PS: When changing from GB2312 to UTF8 some editors might break code some internationalized code. So please make sure to have a copy of your file before converting!